# How to subscribe to another service on error without nesting code

Tags: angular, rxjs

Here is the code I'm using, the `getBudgetDays` doesn't have flatMap/mergeMap even though I've imported it.

```
import { mergeMap, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

I need to subscribe to another service, `budgetTestService`, when there's an error. I'm trying to use `flatMap` to avoid nesting but I'm not sure how to use it.

```
  this.budgetService.getBudgetDays(this.startDate, this.finishDate)
        .subscribe({
          next(budgetDates) {

          },
          error(error) {
            // not sure but I don't think rxjs should have nested callbacks like this.
            self.budgetTestService.getBudgetDates(self.startDate, self.finishDate)

            .subscribe({
              next(budgetDates) {
              },
              error(error) {}
            });
          }
        });
```

Comment: Better is to call one more method within error block instead of nesting function inside.

Answer (score 1):

The clean syntax would be

```js
this.budgetService.getBudgetDays(this.startDate, this.finishDate).pipe(
  catchError(res => this.budgetTestService.getBudgetDates(this.startDate, this.finishDate)),
).subscribe(res => {
  // res = value of getBudgetDays if no error, or getBudgetDates if there is one
});
```

You are using the old, deprecated syntax. Now, it all goes through pipeable operators !

Comment: can I use mergeMap to use result of getBudgetDays and do another subscribe http call?

Comment: @matt `mergeMap` is to be used when you want to chain HTTP calls. In your case, you want to react on an error : you have to use `catchError`. I don't know why you are fixating on `mergeMap`, but your use-case here doesn't allow you to use it !

Comment: considers I have a function processDates only when there is not an error, how can I distinguish if there's an error? I want to use processDates on the res if there is not an error (the res is coming from the budgetTestService).

Comment: If it doesn't work then please provide a [mcve]. If you want to make another call when there is a success, then use `switchMap`, just like you use `catchError` (same syntax)